# .Net MVC5 - Validation to check if string being entered already exists in the json file

Tags: c#, .net, json, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

How do I display a message saying "Sorry, this Product already exists" if the user attempts to enter a Product Name that is already in the List to avoid duplicate entries. the string im looking to check is called within Product inside a JSON file called TechItem.cs

this is what I have tried so far...

in my model,

```
[Required]
[Remote("doesProductExist", "TechEditor", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "This Product already exists within the Quadrant. Please enter a different Product or Go Back and Remove this Product from the List.")]
public string Product { get; set; }
```

and in my controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult doesProductExist(string Product)
{
    var product = (Product);
    return Json(product == null);
}
```

any thoughts?
at the moment the message is just showing any time you enter anything into that textbox. want the message to show up only if what the user is trying to enter matches the sting already in the file exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following method to the Controller:

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public async Task<JsonResult> doesProductExist(string Product)
 {
    var result = 
    await userManager.FindByNameAsync(Product) ?? 
    await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Product);
    return Json(result == null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: Ive put this in, but getting red lines under Task<JsonResult> and userManager

Comment: Are you using Authentication in your application?